# How to pass JSoup Document to another activity and/or class?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

From the MainActivity I call a class (asyncTask) to get a 'Document' (HTML page) from a webpage. It is passed back through an interface (TaskCompleteListner).

From there on I would like to process this 'Document' (i.e. after pressing a button and starting a new Activity/class). I tried various ways, but have not been able to get to this data.

How can I pass a 'Document' type to another Activity and/or class?

Thanks in advance!
Rudy

PS: It would be nice to get an example!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have document type Just save the file to sd card and access it from another activity. if you have large data then store in sqlite while getting from server and use it in next activity, don't try to pass using intents it's bad practice..